# Three.js memory leak regardless of removing mesh from scene

Tags: performance, memory-management, memory-leaks, three.js

[Here is a link](https://jsfiddle.net/spv49o7e/) to a fiddle with what I think is a memory leak I can't get around. I've spent almost all of today trying to find what this memory leak was and explored a lot of three js and googled everything but I can't find the answer to what is going on. I guess geometry.dispose or material.dispose should help here but they don't seem to.

```
Do I somehow still have reference to all of the meshes/geometries/materials 
somewhere even though I can't see them?
```

If you are wondering why I am making so many blocks instead of reusing old ones, it is out of convenience and creating new blocks doesn't slow down my code noticeably, so I don't see why I shouldn't be able to. I just don't understand why my memory never seems to be released and eventually chrome will freeze/crash.

If I never discover a solution I plan to just reuse old blocks, I don't think it will be so bad, we will see.

Comment: I see you've already decided on a solution, but for something like this you might want to consider instancing the blocks. That would allow you to create as many as you wanted, and they'd all reference the one original block. https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my memory leak by reusing the geometry and material. I don't know how creating new geometries/materials creates a memory leak but it really made a huge difference.